# PHP Error - All Files or Directories created are 0

Tags: php, html, error-handling, syntax-error

I was recently coding a registration script and wanted to create a folder inside another folder called "users". Somehow, the folder created was in the root path (where the php script is located) and the files, that were supposed to be written inside the folder were in a file called 0. Here's the code:

```
if (!isset($_POST["method"])){
                die("Error");
            }
            if (!isset($_POST["usernamefld"])){
                die("Error");
            }
            if (!isset($_POST["passwordfld"])){
                die("Error");
            }
            if ($_POST["method"] == "register"){
                if (!isset($_POST["emailfld"])){
                    die("Error");
                }

                if(is_dir("./users/"+$_POST["usernamefld"])){
                    die("Taken");
                }

                mkdir("/users/"+$_POST["usernamefld"]);
                echo "test";



            }
```

The Folder "0" is always empty when created.

Comment: Because concatenation in php is done with `.`, not `+`

Comment: By the way, if you want url like `/users/mike/` creating folders is a __wrong__ approach.

Comment: Better to use a mysql database.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As @u_mulder has stated, in PHP we concat strings and variables with a "." and not the "+" symbol. Based on that, this should help with your particular issue.

```
if (!isset($_POST["method"])){
    die("Error");
}
if (!isset($_POST["usernamefld"])){
    die("Error");
}
if (!isset($_POST["passwordfld"])){
    die("Error");
}

if ($_POST["method"] == "register"){
    if (!isset($_POST["emailfld"])){
        die("Error");
    }

    if(is_dir("./users/". $_POST["usernamefld"])){
        die("Taken");
    }

    mkdir("/users/". $_POST["usernamefld"]);
    echo "test";
 }
```